# Win CE and ASP: How to read/write a file?

Tags: asp-classic, windows-ce

I haven't found any answer on the web, maybe one of you knows the answer:
With Win CE and MS ASP, how can I read a file or do any IO-Operations?
I have this example code which doesn't work at all because the FileSystemObject doesn't exist in CE.

```
<%
 dim fs,tfile
 set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 set tfile=fs.CreateTextFile("c:\somefile.txt")
 tfile.WriteLine("Hello World!")
 tfile.close
 set tfile=nothing
 set fs=nothing
 %>
```

Is there any alternative to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems in your code.  Most notably is that, as you noted, the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` doesn't exist in Windows CE.  Also, CE doesn't have drive letters, so even if it did, your `CreateTextFile` call would fail.

The solution, if you want to stick with the built-in web server, is not a simple one.  Windows CE doesn't have any COM object out-of-the-box that will do what you want.  The typical solution would be to create a new COM DLL (using the Win32 Smart Device ATL project wizard) and then implement an object that does what you want.  Using the same object model as the FSO would make the code easier for ASP devs to read.  Make sure you also implement [`IObjectSafety`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488509%28v=WinEmbedded.60%29.aspx), otherwise the browser can't load it.

Next, you'll have to deploy and register the DLL to every device that will be hitting your page.  I'll leave the logistics of that to you.

Answer (score 1):

When you mention WinCE do you mean you are using it as the server or just the computer you are browsing the site with?

Regardless of what machine is your server, it is important to make sure the path you choose (where you put "c:\...") is one where the permissions are set open enough to allow IIS and ASP to write files to that folder. I would start by picking a different folder and recommend that folder be a subfolder of the inetpub folder.

Comment: I use it as server. And I want to read and write files. Let's forget about the path, my question is only about the object I can't create. What can I replace this object with?

Comment: I see. A component I have used in the past that works very well (see the File Manager subcomponent) is http://fileup.softartisans.com/ <-- I don't know for sure if it will work with CE.